# When multiple boot, should you use have FAT32 EFI drive for each OS?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, grub-efi

I am booting Windows, Ubuntu, and Manjaro and I have a problem in bootloader. Is it ideal to have separate EPS partition for each OS like one EFS in `Windows`, one in `Ubuntu`, and one in `Manjaro`?
Or I can use the EPS partition of `Windows` for all OSes?

Comment: Is this the installer, or after install? And are all systems installed in UEFI boot mode or some in old BIOS boot mode? What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Preinstalled Windows since 2012 is UEFI, so other installs need to be UEFI.  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This is installer. And I am using UEFI (not secured) in an Acer Aspire laptop i3 with pre-installed Windows.

Comment: Some install tools create either UEFI or BIOS boot install flash drives. ISO is configured to be both. What tool are you using? You may have to turn on settings in Acer's UEFI. Also links on how to create a bootable DVD or USB flash drive, from Windows or Ubuntu
http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download  &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi   Lots of info on USB boot for installing
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: @OrganicMarble partially yes, I got it! Thank you. I also want to know the pros and cons of the two scenario.

Comment: @Player1 there's a bug somewhere that says the Ubuntu installer will ignore the EFI partition you tell it to use and use the first one it finds!

Answer (score 1):

windows require an exFAT and installs from NFTS, Ubuntu is ext4 3 2 and exFAT and install from FAT64 or FAT32, and Manjaro is ext4 3 2 and exFAT and install from FAT 32 but this should not be a problem but if you are having trouble with choosing the OS from boot that is a different question.

EDIT: if you are having trouble with loading the other OSes then get ubuntu on USB live boot it and run in a command line (don't click the link)

sudo apt install software-properties-common; 
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"; 
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; 
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

this will install boot-repair then find it in applications and run recommended repair.